# Why does Google Enhanced Ecommerce add to cart works as a click?

Tags: nuxt.js, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

In my Nuxt.js project on add to cart button there is a function which is supposed to add product in cart. Before logic of adding to cart I added code for GA Ecommerce. And when I click the button, on Google Analytics page I can see that this product is added to `Product List Click` section, but not in `Products Adds to Cart`.

There is this code:

```js
addToCart() {
  this.$ga.ecommerce.addProduct({
    'id': this.itemProduct.id,
    'name': this.itemProduct.text
  });
  this.$ga.ecommerce.setAction('add', {
    'list': this.itemProduct.text.split(' ')[0],
  });
...
}
```

**BUT**, at the same time I have literally the same function, which also adds product to cart, and it works.

For other example, this is how function on clicks works (works correctly):

```js
onProductClick(item) {
  this.$ga.ecommerce.addProduct({
    'id': item.id,
    'name': item.text,
   });
  this.$ga.ecommerce.setAction('click', {
    'list': item.text.split(' ')[0]
   });
}
```

And I have no idea, why this happens that way. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you `await` the `this.$ga` method to be sure that it resolves properly before proceeding?

Comment: Also, giving us only this and 2 exact same snippets of code will not be useful IMO. Try to find some other approach as of from where this may come from.

Comment: Async function with `await` doesn't work. I mean, without it function works in other places.